# how to import COM dll in D

Tags: dll, com, import, d

I'm trying to create an D application which uses a (third party) COM .dll so I can scrape a text box of another application so I can sound an error when a certain string shows up.

However the third party doesn't provide .lib, .def or .h files that go with the dll (atleast with the free trial version). I can create the .lib file with the [implib](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/implib.html) tool but I don't see any of the library's functions in the created .lib.

Their (visual c++) samples use the `#import` directive to link it in however that is of no use for me ...

On a side note how can I get the proper interfaces (in a .di with boilerplate that does the linking) of the dll automatically? I ask so the correctness of the linkage doesn't depend on my (likely to be incorrect) translation of the functions. They do have a [webpage](http://wiki.screen-scraper.deskperience.com/wiki/TextCaptureX_SDK) which gives all functions but the object model is a bit chaotic to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, COM libraries only expose a few functions, required to (un)register the library and to create objects.
You can however view the interfaces and functions in a COM .dll using the [OLE/COM Object Viewer](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic68780.html). It seems it might be able to output header files (.h). Afterwards, maybe you could use [htod](http://www.d-programming-language.org/htod.html) as a starting point to converting everything to D interfaces.

The DMD distribution seems to include a .COM sample (*chello.d, dclient.d, dserver.d*), and at first glance it doesn't look like it would require any LIBs explicitly.

Unfortunately, I've never actually used COM in D, so I can't advise any further. I hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score 1):

While I have yet to actually do COM work myself, I am trying to revive [Juno](http://dsource.org/projects/juno) over on [Github/he-the-great](https://github.com/he-the-great/Juno-Windows-Class-Library). Part of the project is [tlbimpd](http://dsource.org/projects/juno/wiki/TypeLibraryImporter) which is what will output a D file from a DLL.

I've tested the examples and successfully run tlbimpd. Please do try things out for your use and submit any issues.